# Finding point isUnder() with only isAbove() function

Tags: java

I have recently recieved a question from a university that i'm studying
to build a class named `point`.

one of the class methods has a `isAbove()` function which compares 2 points Y-axis. the higher y-axis value will be "above" the other point.

I've build the following function

```
public boolean isAbove(Point other) {
return _y > other.getY();
}
```

but on the other function isUnder, thier asking to use ONLY the `isAbove` function.

```
public boolean isUnder(Point other) {
return !(isAbove(other));
}
```

but what will happan when the y-axis value will be equal? it will also return "true". which is not right. 
so what do you think they meant to do?

Comment: I did, they said thier not answering this question. thats why im asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `isAbove` to implement an `isLevel` method (I concede this is not the best name, but the meaning is two points have the same y-axis value):

```
public boolean isLevel(Point other) {
    return !isAbove(other) && !other.isAbove(this);
}
```

Having done this, implementing `isUnder` becomes easy:

```
public boolean isUnder(Point other) {
    return !(isAbove(other) || isLevel(other));
}
```

**EDIT**: actually, an even easier way would be to say that A is under B if and only if B is above A:

```
public boolean isUnder(Point other) {
    return other.isAbove(this);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The university wants you to come up with

```
public boolean isUnder(Point other) {
 return other.isAbove(this);
}
```

For when the other point is above this point, this point is under the other point.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion

You can see you can't use `boolen` as return type if there can be more than two result for scenario. So you can return `String` saying `above`, `under` or `same hight`.